# Comparing objects in a list inside drl file

Tags: drools

I am having a list of objects like [man1,man2,man3,man4] of the type Man.

I need to compare the 4 objects as follows.
(man1.name == man2.name,man2.name == man3.name,man3.name == man4.name)

How to do it inside a drl. I cannot iterate the objects like this, the drl is comparing each object with all the other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that the order of your `Man` objects is important, I'm guessing they must contain some kind of `id` or property that allows you to order them. If that is the case (and I'm assuming the name of this attribute is `id`), you can try something along these lines:

```
rule "Some Rule" 
when 
  $m1: Man()
  not Man(id > $m1.id)
  forall( 
    Man(name == $m1.name)
  )
then 
  //Action
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Ok So.. If i have to do a group by name for all the four objects.. is there any way to do that?

Comment: Group those objects which have the same name.. Is that possible??